# How does a photon interact with EM field of a nucleus thus exchange momentum and recoil the nucleus when pair production happens?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics

> The photon must be near a nucleus in order to satisfy conservation of momentum, as an electron–positron pair produced in free space cannot satisfy conservation of both energy and momentum.[4] Because of this, when pair production occurs, the atomic nucleus receives some recoil.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production

How does photon interact with EM field of a nucleus? How does that happen?